# .NET web service with many requests

Tags: c#, .net, sql, web-services

i have a .net web-service in some server.
this web-service gets lots of requests per day.
there is an android project that allot of people using it and exchange data with this ws.
something like 20 requests per minute.

recently im getting allot of timeouts from the server and i cant find out what is the reason.
did i write the web.config wrong? or it something else?

here is my system.web on my config:

```
    <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/></assemblies></compilation>
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="9000" maxRequestLength="500000"/>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpSoap12"/>
            <add name="HttpSoap"/>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
</system.web>
```

what can i do to improve?
can i set max requests or max bandwidth?

Comment: what exactly does your WS do ? how is memory consumption ? how is the network bandwidth of your server ?

Comment: the ws works with 3 different other web-services and exchange data. its getting images (something like 2 every request) and sending them to another server.

Comment: Can you use WMI / performance counters? i would try looking at the number of outstanding requests, IIS queue length, etc ... It seems that you are on the limit of what the webservice can handle. When possible, use multiple app pool instances (see 'web garden' in IIS), or use multple load balanced web servers ('web farming').

Comment: ok, i will try. thanks. more suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set debug="false"
Debug="true" forces web server to run single-threaded

Comment: im sure it helps alot but it didnt fix my timeouts problem.

Comment: What OS are you on? Server 2008 R2? Windows 7?